# Jbutton acction listener

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, frame

I am trying to create a form. there is a button that when clicking the button, a photo which is specified would appear. my problem is, when I click the button, the picture pops up and if the cursor passes the form boundary, the image disappears. here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import static java.lang.Math.min;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SeamCarving extends JFrame
{     
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(new File("path"));

    final BufferedImage[] toPaint = new BufferedImage[]{input};
    final Frame frame = new Frame("Seams") {

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            final BufferedImage im = toPaint[0];
            if (im != null) {
                g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, this);
            }
        }
    };
    frame.setSize(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(startButton);

    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            BufferedImage out = input;
            out = deleteVerticalSeam(out);
            toPaint[0] = out;
            frame.repaint();
            System.out.println("Do Something Clicked");
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: @Christian this is like a SSCCE except u need to enter a path for image. cause  have no idea where is  the image path and name in different systems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't override `update`, this isn't how painting is achieved in Swing.  Attempting to paint directly to a top level container like `JFrame` is problematic at best.

Instead, start with a `JPanel` and use it's `paintComponent` method instead.  Make sure you call `super.paintComponent` as well.

In fact, you could probably just use a `JLabel` to display the image instead.

Take a look at;

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

For more details

**Updated with example**

I still think a `JLabel` would be simpler solution, but what do I know.

[image: Before][image: After]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SeamCarving {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SeamCarving();
    }

    public SeamCarving() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage input;
        private BufferedImage[] toPaint;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                input = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\hold\\thumbnails\\2005-09-29-3957.jpeg"));
                toPaint = new BufferedImage[1];
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
            startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    BufferedImage out = input;
                    out = input; //deleteVerticalSeam(out);
                    toPaint[0] = out;
                    repaint();
                    System.out.println("Do Something Clicked");
                }
            });
            add(startButton);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return input == null ? new Dimension(400, 400) : new Dimension(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (toPaint[0] != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.drawImage(input, 0, 0, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem with overriding `update` is the `paint` subsystem can choose to avoid calling and end up calling `paint` directly, circumventing your painting.

Painting also involves painting child components (like your button) and borders, which you've conveniently discarded by not calling `super.update`.

Comment: it is not a Jframe, it is only a Frame

Comment: And that makes a difference how? The repaint engine can actually skip the `update` method completely and simply call `paint` directly...

Comment: it does, cause if i just change the Frame to Jframe without any other changes to the code, the pic wont be visible

Comment: Then stop painting to a top level container.  Use `JPanel`, you're breaking the paint chain and mix heavy and light weight components will cause no end of trouble...

Comment: I've added a runnable example

Comment: yup, it is working now. was there anyway to just modify my code or I did it completely wrong?

Comment: Sorry to say, it was completely wrong. Windows are complex containers which contain many differnt containers, you really don't want to mess with how they paint